# Input placeholder from ViewModel metadata in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Is it possible to set up the built-in `asp-for` tag helper to take the input placeholder from the `[Display(Prompt = "This is the placeholder")]` attribute in the view model.

```
[Display(Name="Name", Prompt = "This is the placeholder")]        
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In MVC 5 I am able to achieve this by adding additional logic in my editor templates and checking the `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark` property. For example:

```
@model string
@{
    Dictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    htmlAttributes.Add("class", "form-control");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark))
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("placeholder", ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark);
    }
}
@Html.Label("")
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, htmlAttributes)
@Html.ValidationMessage("", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

But now in ASP.NET Core 1.0 I would like to start using the new tag helpers approach. By default, the build in `asp-for` helper simply ignores the `Prompt` attribute value.

Having my own custom implementation of the `asp-for` attribute, e.g. `my-asp-for` is an option and most probably I will end up having it for the sake of maintainability and reusing additional logic. 
But then the `Watermark` property is no longer present in the `ModelMetadata`, i.e. there is no such thing as `For.Metadata.Watermark`.

The only place I can see the `Prompt` value in the `asp-for` helper is somewhat hidden.

[image]

So I have two questions. 
Is there a smarter way to do that ? 
Is it a bad practice to take the placeholder from the viewmodel metadata, i.e. I should explicitly specify it it in the razor file ?

Answer (score 55):

I have just done a quick test and if I understand you correctly, this appears to work out of the box for me with the default VS template:

Model:

```cs
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email", Prompt = "example@example.org")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

View snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Tags, new { placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Tags) })
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think this code is understandable. There is no need for additional explanation.  Especially this part. => Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Tags)